# Browse DropBox in Android SDK

Tags: android, dropbox

How can I browse files stored on dropbox from within Android app?
I used dropbox API and now I can log into dropbox
but I don't know how to browse for a file of certain type ( .RTF in my case) in the dropbox folders of the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546153/list-all-the-folder-and-files-of-dropbox-using-dropbox-api

Hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just browse all formats, you need decoder for every format. Also you can pass the task to any program that supports reading format your app doesn't support. [RTF specification](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)

Comment: I mean how can I launch an activity ( intent) to browse dropbox, using installing dropbox app.