# Getting File names from Dropbox particular folder in ArrayList

Tags: android, dropbox

I have some image files stored in a folder on Dropbox. I wanted to get all the file names in ArrayList and display those images in ListView or say GridView. Dropbox api is not well documented for beginner.Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this link it may help you :-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546153/list-all-the-folder-and-files-of-dropbox-using-dropbox-api?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Dropbox is far from the worst I've seen. You need to use the metadata path like my example below.

```
 List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
 Entry entries = mDropboxApi.metadata("/metadata", 100, null, true, null);

 for (Entry e : entries.contents) {
     if (!e.isDeleted && !e.isDir) {
         arrList.add(e.fileName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for my last comment. I put it wrongly. I wanted to ask you that can you help me with flickr Api to get photos from flickr set. Flickr is out of the question here. :-P @Nick Cardoso